# MvvmCross with a MapFragment

Tags: xamarin, google-maps-api-2, mvvmcross

I am unable to create an activity using the google map v2 fragment.  Custom fragments work fine, this is only a problem with a MapFragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<fragment
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/mapfragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Here is the error:

```
mvx:Diagnostic: 36.27 Showing ViewModel TruckWashMapViewModel
[0:] mvx:Diagnostic: 36.27 Showing ViewModel TruckWashMapViewModel
07-03 17:24:51.184 I/mono-stdout(16230): mvx:Diagnostic: 36.27 Showing ViewModel TruckWashMapViewModel
07-03 17:24:51.214 I/Choreographer(16230): Skipped 297 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
Resolved pending breakpoint at 'c:\_Application\BLUBCNMOBL\src\BLUBCNMOBL.Droid\Views\TruckWashMapView.cs:17,1' to OnCreate [0x00001].
[0:] mvx:Diagnostic: 40.71 Loading new ViewModel from Intent with Extras
[0:] mvx:Diagnostic: 40.71 Loading new ViewModel from Intent with Extras
07-03 17:24:55.629 I/mono-stdout(16230): mvx:Diagnostic: 40.71 Loading new ViewModel from Intent with Extras
[0:] 
MvxBind:Error: 42.60 View type not found - fragment
[0:] MvxBind:Error: 42.60 View type not found - fragment
07-03 17:24:57.511 I/mono-stdout(16230): MvxBind:Error: 42.60 View type not found - fragment
```

Looking through the further through the stack trace, it looks like the is an error with the API key.  But I do have my API key in the AndroidManifest.xml.

```
07-05 14:55:02.231 I/MonoDroid(31877): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/logo"
                 android:debuggable="true"
                 android:enabled="true"
                 android:persistent="false"
                 android:allowClearUserData="true">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="xxx" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have posted my entire AndroidManifest.xml.  The problem was that I had 2 Application nodes within the manifest.

Comment: Same blind bastard here :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this problem occurring for any fragment? Or just for a map fragment?

Can you work around this problem using a ViewGroup and dynamically loading your fragment into it?

As a reference, the N+1 video for fragments included `<fragment>` tags - n=26 - this showed fragments being loaded and was recorded with nuget packages 3.0.8.1

See

- https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/blob/master/N-26-Fraggle/Rock.Droid/Resources/Layout/FirstView.axml
- https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/master/N-26-Fraggle/packages

If it's all fragments which are now broken, then i guess something has broken since this 3.0.8.1 version - in which case report an issue and/or a fix to the project.

If this problem is specific to your maps import, then I guess you will have to do more debugging and investigation to work the issue out.

Comment: I've added more information to the question.  This is occurring only for a google maps fragment, and I have found more information in the stack trace saying the API key isn't found.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not aware of any way mvx interferes with the api key lookup - so I can't really comment any more on this. Note - I'm not saying that this isn't somehow related to MvvmCross - but I am saying that your new updates suggests that mvvmCross is more of a bystander in this one (we might still be standing in the wrong place at the wrong time... but no real clue currently about how or why or where the right place to stand is!). Hopefully someone who understands the Xamarin.Android-Java-GooglePlay relationship more will be able to assist. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using unmodified version of MvvmCross (3.0.8.1) then you need to use com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment instead of com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment

Try to use this to display map fragment

```
<fragment
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/mapfragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

I have observed similar issue with the API key. Mine was caused by wrong setup in Google APIs Console. There are actually two services to choose from "Google Maps Android API v2" and "Google Maps API v2". Can you please verify in Services tab that you have actually activated "Google Maps Android API v2" service.

Comment: You are right that I was using the wrong MapFragment.  When I left the code like this I was getting a map fragment error.  Now that I have it switched to SupportMapFragment, I'm getting the API key error.  Updated the question, thanks.